# Not receiving emails, but Mailgun shows 100% delivery rate

Tags: mailgun

I'm using a CMS to send emails when a form is submitted. Its configured to use smtp.mailgun.org:587 with the username postmaster@domain.com. I'm using Google Apps for my email, so in this case the email account I'm receiving emails at is support@domain.com. Customers fill out a form and enter their email address is used as the "from" address and the "to" address is support@domain.com. I don't see anything in my Junk folder in Gmail. Mailgun is getting all the emails and marking them as sent/received, but I simply am not getting the emails in Gmail, thus not getting support emails from my customers. What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue was I had mxa.mailgun.org and mxb.mailgun.org added in my MX Records on my host (Linode). Removing those records fixed the issue.

Comment: I kinda have the same issue. But I did delete MX records and it didn't help. Did you leave MX blank?

Comment: I found the problem, I need to add google MX record in my DNS settings on Vultr